# Determine the objects used as generic parameters from a stack trace

Tags: c#, generics

My project has a base class with a function I can call to log when I enter a method.
Other classes inherit from this base class and add other functionality.
A third layer of classes can inherit from this middle layer and often override some of the functions.
The logging function's purpose is to allow me to easily note in the logs which function I entered most recently and as such, it is imperative to know if the function is in the base class, or if it is one of the overridden functions.

The following code (modified for brevity) does what I want very nicely.  HOWEVER, I've recently added class with generic parameters to my project.  While this function still fulfills its purpose, I'd like to tweak it to show what type was used to instantiate the generic class.

Here's some sample code (this will run in LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
    var d = new DerivedClass();
    d.DoWork();
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected void LogMethodEntry([CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
    {
        //NOTE: All error handling and null checking has been removed for brevity
        var frameMethod = new StackTrace(1).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(); // skip one frame as this is the Log function we are currently in

        // This gives "EnrichedClass`1".
        // I want "EnrichedClass<MyGenericParameterType>"
        var parentName = frameMethod.DeclaringType.Name;
        //frameMethod.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments().First().Name
        // is the closest I could get, but it just gives me "T",
        // from the declaration "EnrichedClass<T>", which isn't helpful

        Console.WriteLine($"Starting method {methodName} as implemented in {parentName}.");

    }

    protected virtual void DoAFunction()
    {
        LogMethodEntry();
    }
}
public class EnrichedClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    protected override void DoAFunction()
    {
        LogMethodEntry();
        Console.WriteLine($"Note I can access concrete types at this level: \"{nameof(EnrichedClass<T>)}<{typeof(T).Name}>\".");
        base.DoAFunction();
    }
}
public class MyGenericParameterType
{
}

public class DerivedClass : EnrichedClass<MyGenericParameterType>
{
    protected override void DoAFunction()
    {
        LogMethodEntry();
        base.DoAFunction();
    }
    
    public void DoWork()
    {
        DoAFunction();
    }
}
```

The output from running this is:

```
Starting method DoAFunction as implemented in DerivedClass.
Starting method DoAFunction as implemented in EnrichedClass`1.
Note: I have access to concrete types at this level as shown here: "EnrichedClass<MyGenericParameterType>".
Starting method DoAFunction as implemented in BaseClass.
```

Which works--it DOES tell me everything I need to know.  HOWEVER, if I could get that 2nd line to say this instead:

```
Starting method DoAFunction as implemented in EnrichedClass<MyGenericParameterType>.
```

that would be much more useful in the logs. Is there a way to do that? While the 3rd line demonstrates that what I want CAN be done from within the EnrichedClass's function itself, I'm starting to think it cannot be done with a stack trace at a less-derived level, esp. since when you read stack trace dumps, they only ever show the "EnrichedClass`1" style of names.  I *COULD* do something where I pass data into "LogMethodEntry", but that totally defeats a primary goal of that method, which is to avoid boilerplate code, so I'm not open to that approach.

(NOTE: I'm stuck in .NET Framework 4.5, so if there is a .NET Core or .NET5/6 solution, I'd be interested in hearing it, but it doesn't help me here)

Comment: Your `frameMethod` is of type `MethodBase`.  It has an `IsGenericMethod` property and a `GetGenericArguments` method that hands you back a collection of `System.Type` instances (each of which has a `Name` property).  Is that enough for what you want to do

Comment: @Flydog57 the method itself is not generic, so `GetGenericArguments` should return empty collection.